# How to save multiple items from different ListBox elements using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm working with ListBoxes in WPF and am trying to save items from different list boxes into the same file. As for now each listbox gets their own file.

This is my code so far:

```
private void OnSaveAs()
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (save.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        //File.WriteAllText(save.FileName, InputsMinMax.Text);
    }


    if (this.InputsMV.Items.Count > 0 && save.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (FileStream S = File.Open(save.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
            {
                foreach (var aa in InputsMV.Items)
                    st.WriteLine(aa.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish. You wont face this if you go for `MVVM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save items from multiple `ListBox` elements you can create a simple file format where for each element you save its name, number of items and item values:

```
[line 0]     ListBox name
[line 1]     Number of items - n
[line 2]     Item 1
[line 3]     Item 2
 ...         ...     
[line n + 1] Item n 
[line n + 2] Next ListBox name
```

Note that this format assumes that items do not contain new line characters.

Then you can save items from all elements like this:

```
private void OnSaveAs()
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (save.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (FileStream S = File.Open(save.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
            {
                // Iterate over ListBox elements
                foreach (var myListBox in MyListBoxes)
                {
                    // Write the name of the ListBox element
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(myListBox.Name);

                    // Write the number of elements
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(myListBox.Items.Count);

                    // Write the elements
                    foreach (var item in myListBox.Items)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "MyListBoxes"  a list where I put all my boxes?

Comment: @Anna Yes, you can collect them in a list.

Comment: Hm.. @Krzysztof. I saved them in a list like: List<ListBox> listBoxes = new List<ListBox>(); and then tried to iterate over the listbox elements like you told me: foreach(var myListBox in listBoxes) but it doesn't work. When I open the text file it's empty even though I have items in my list boxes.

Comment: It works now! I think I used your "old" version. I saw now that you had edited it. Thank you so much! Do you know if it is possible to make the name of the ListBox bold? Tried googling it but didn't find anything.

Comment: @Anna Glad to help. I am not sure if I understand what do you mean by "make the name of the ListBox bold", could you please clarify?

Comment: In every iteration it will write the name of the different ListBox elements, I would like the name to be bold, for example: **Listbox 1** @KrzysztofBracha

Comment: @Anna Plain text files (.txt) consist only of characters and you cannot apply formatting to them. For the names to be able to appear bold you would need first to save them in a specific format (e.g. docx, html), add formatting, and then open them in a specific application (e.g. Word, web browser).

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you! @KrzysztofBracha